# asp.net impersonation not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, impersonation

I need to write on a share path (In different server) from my web server. I try this by impersonationg a network account which has access to write on that server. When I try this by running from my Visual Studio it works. But when I publish it in the IIS of the web server and it does't work.

can some one provide some insight.?

Comment: Locally you don't use IIs, my guess is that IIs is not configured correctly.

Comment: Please post code (or at least links to samples you took code from) - either your impersonation is not impersonating OR account does not have permissions. Please check Environment.UserName while you think you are inside impersonated block of code.

Comment: open your VS project file in notepad/word pad, and set IIS tag value to true, now when you run the project, it will behave like IIS environment, and you might get a clue to solve the issue.

Comment: I have used code Project code. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10090/A-small-C-Class-for-impersonating-a-User

Comment: IIs stands for Internet Information Server.  It is a microsoft product.  I expect you are running your web site on it when you use the server.

Comment: In any case, post your web config -- I expect you did not set it up right.

Comment: Hogan, I have just used the code from the above mentioned code project link. I have't made any changes to web.config

Comment: Is there a way to find out the type of network user account I have?